# Python import from central location

Tags: python, import

I know that Python import strategy has been a matter of discussion in countless posts, but I have not yet found a satisfactory answer yet.

I am building a large Python project, where I try to group modules in subdirectories in a sensible way, thus creating a directory structure that becomes a few levels deep in some branches. In many of my modules I need to import some basic module that I would like to keep in a central place at the top level. For example, I have a lot of different classes that implement 3D objects, and I have one general rotation matrix class that I would like to apply to all of these objects. I therefore would have to import that from a parent directory, and the fact that Python does not make that easy somehow indicates that this is not encouraged.

I know that I can hack something together by adding to `sys.path`, but somehow that does seem like a hack. Since it looks like I have to bend over backwards to achieve what I'm trying to do here, I am questioning my architectural approach, although it seems like a natural way to put general stuff that applies to many situations at top level. The alternative for easy imports would be to duplicate the class to be imported at all the levels where it is needed, but that cannot be the right way to do it. So I'm asking for guidance on the proper way to organize Python modules.

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the import confusion comes from running your programs as scripts instead of modules.
When you have a structure like this in your root:

```
├── foo
│   └── my3d.py
└── utils
    └── rotationmatrix.py
```

rotationmatrix.py:

```
import numpy as np
import quaternion # this is numpy-quaterion


def make_rot_from_axangles(axis_angles):
    return quaternion.as_rotation_matrix(quaternion.from_rotation_vector(axis_angles))
```

my3d.py:

```
from utils import rotationmatrix


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rotmx = rotationmatrix.make_rot_from_axangles([1,2,3])
    print(rotmx)
```

Then you can run your my3d module like a script

```
python foo/my3d.py
```

But this will fail without the sys.path hack, since it won't find your utils module: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'"

You can add the sys path hack at the beginning of my3d.py for a quick fix:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
```

But what you want to do instead is call your module as a module (duh :D) with:

```
python -m foo.my3d
```

This works, but in case you change it to a relative import, it won't

```
from ..utils import rotationmatrix
```

This results in "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package".

That is something you can fix by structuring all your folders/files so that they have a single common ancestor folder. For eg:

```
└── myawesome3d
    ├── foo
    │   └── my3d.py
    └── utils
        └── rotationmatrix.py
```

Then you must call your my3d module through myawesome3d ancestor:

```
python -m myawesome3d.foo.my3d
```

And voilá, relative imports work too. This might not even be the final form though, because in some cases you actually want to use an "src layout"

https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/

My personal preference is to always use the src layout (unless for very simple "one-shot" scripts or scripts that does not need to be called from outside the project), because it makes imports work nicely, it enables you to separate your tests from your src code, it makes building a package easy, and it helps you see how someone might want to use your package from outside your package code. In src layout you want to use an editable install of your package while developing, and once you have something ready, you build your new package version.
There is a reason why projects like hatch gain traction:
https://hatch.pypa.io/1.6/config/project-templates/#src-layout

This is basically a package you can use to make new empty projects (kind of like "cargo new" in Rust), and you can set src layout in it to be the default. The empty skeleton of the project helps you organize your code from the start.