# Sphinx autodoc import problems

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a python project main file that resides in `C:\b_tool\b.py`. I start it from `C:` with `python -m b_tool.b`. `b.py` imports all kinds of other modules.

I would like to add a Sphinx folder like here `C:\b_tool\Docs\Sphinx`. How would I specify the path (or additional options) in Sphinx's `conf.py` such that when Sphinx does its thing, it does not run into import problems, because that is what is happening currently.

I created a reduced example:
Directory structure:

```
b_tool
 |
 |--b.py
 |
 |--sub
 |   |
 |   |--sub.py
 |
 |--Doc
     |
     |--Sphinx
```

b.py:

```
from b_tool.sub.sub import Subclass
a = Subclass()
print(a.a)
```

sub.py:

```
class Subclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3.14;
```

I can run b.py from outside of the b_tool folder with `python -m b_tool.b`. By doing it this way, I can import modules from any subdirectory by specifying the absolute path to the module. If I run b.py as a script, I lose a lot of flexibility in this regard. At least I have not found a good way of doing it in another way, and this method was recommended to me in the post that I cited above.

It is not possible to call b.py as a script, that will return a ModuleNotFoundError.

Now I would like to have the Sphinx machine in the folder as indicated (will probably move it to somewhere else altogether later). The question is now what do I tell Sphinx so that it is able to go through the files without running into import problems?

Here's the Sphinx files:

index.rst:

```
Welcome to B's documentation!
=============================

.. automodule:: b
    :members:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

conf.py:

```
project = 'B'
copyright = '2023, John Doe'
author = 'John Doe'
    
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']
```

Now when I run `make html`, I get the following warning/error:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'b'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'b_tool'
```

Comment: This project structure implies that the `b_tool` folder **is not intended to represent a package**. As such, it makes more sense to start from inside the folder, and then just run `python -m b`, or even `python b.py`. The latter can be made to work from other folders by specifying the path.

Comment: b.py is the top-level module of a hierarchy of modules. I am very happy with this structure, as it allows me to do painless imports (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75895815/python-import-from-central-location). But I have to call it from outside of the top-level folder, as described above, for it to run. Calling it like you suggest leads to import failures. But my question was how to make Sphinx work with this structure, not alternative ways of calling the main module.

Comment: What exactly are the import problems? There is nothing we can reproduce here.

Comment: The import errors are ModuleNotFoundError. But you are right, there was nothing to reproduce. I edited my original post to include a minimal example of the python code structure.

Comment: The question is still unclear to me. The question title is "Sphinx autodoc import problems", but the minimal example does not demonstrate anything related to Sphinx usage.

Comment: Added the Sphinx code now. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: b.py is in the `b_tool` package. It works if you use `.. automodule:: b_tool.b`.

Answer (score 0):

At the very top of your `conf.py` file you can add

```
import os                                                                                                                                                                                                          
import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                         
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

which, depending on how many dots you give to `abspath`, it will make sphinx look for source code the number of dots levels up from where the `conf.py` file is located (in my example, 1 above, as the first dot `.` means "here in this local directory").

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was aware of that option, and I did use it. Sphinx does find the module but fails at importing the submodules. I have the feeling I gotta tell Sphinx to use the -m switch. The mechanism how Sphinx goes through the modules and what it does is unclear to me.